# How does anti-parallel diode for limit current work?

Tags: diode-clamp

I read [OPA627 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa627.pdf).

This datasheet mentioned over voltage protected with 2 diode in figure 33a:

[image]

I can understand how it do.

Vi will be clamp when Vi > |Vs| .

But the figure 33b:

[image]

Datasheet said it's a over current protected.

How does it work?

Comment: I don't find the datasheet says so. I find *input protection [for] I/V converters of inverting amplifiers*

Comment: OK! let me modify title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Datasheet said it's a over current protected. How does it work?*

When the input current is within the limits of the op-amp's output sink or source capabilities, the inverting input becomes a virtual ground. This means that the op-amp is successfully holding the inverting input (via the feedback resistor) at 0 volts (the same voltage as the no-inverting input).

This is a useful configuration for a current to voltage converter because the back-to-back diodes play no role and do not conduct.

However, when the input current goes beyond what the op-amp output can sink or source, the virtual ground is lost and, the inverting input may rise to a voltage that can damage the op-amp. Hence, adding back-to-back diodes prevents this from happening (providing the diodes don't get damaged by excessive overload current).